# Is it possible to create a Domain Class which has Multiple FK Columns to same PK?

Tags: sql, entity-framework, database-design

I'm a newbie to designing database.

I have problem how to define a domain class which has multiple foreign keys linked with a same primary key.

Here is my model:

```
namespace OceanFmsSystem.Domain
{
    public class ExportTemplate
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public List<ExportBooking> ExportBookings { get; set; }
        public string TemplateName { get; set; }
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string Incoterms { get; set; } 
        public string IncotermsDetail { get; set; }
        public string PaymentTerm{ get; set; }
        public int CountryOriginId { get; set; }
        public int CountryDestinationId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

What I want to do is that `CountryOriginId` & `CountryDestinationId` should refer to the below class as foreign keys:

```
namespace OceanFmsSystem.Domain
{
    public class Country
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string CountryCode { get; set; }
        public string CountryName { get; set; }
    }
}
```

As far as I know, in EF Core there is an convention which I should name a foreign key as below for migration from code to database.

```
public type ClassNameOfPrimaryKeyId { get; set;}
```

Is there any possible way to make this happens?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, possible. Your class should look like this:

```
public class ExportTemplate
{
    //...

    public int CountryOriginId { get; set; }
    public Country CountryOrigin { get; set; }

    public int CountryDestinationId { get; set; }
    public Country CountryDestination { get; set; }
}
```

EF is smart enough to figure the Ids by convention. If you do not wish to follow the convention you can use [ForeignKey] attribute on the properties to configure the FK:

```
[ForeignKey("Origin")]
public int MyOriginId { get; set; }
public Country Origin { get; set; }
```